# SQL (Presto) - 'compress' rows when date ranges are sequential

Tags: sql, presto

I have this data (sample):

```
event_id    period_start    period_end  rating
100269      2/8/2016        6/30/2016   1
100269      6/30/2016       12/31/2016  1
100269      12/31/2016      6/30/2017   2
100269      6/30/2017       12/31/2017  2
```

I would like to "compress" the rows when the periods (`period_start`, `period_end`) are immediately sequential AND the rating is the same.  Desired output would be:

```
event_id    period_start    period_end  rating
100269      2/8/2016        12/31/2016  1
100269      12/31/2016      12/31/2017  2
```

Note that within this dataset, not all periods are directly sequential for some `event_id`.  Here is an example and the desired output:

```
event_id    period_start    period_end  rating
100300      2/8/2016        6/30/2016   1
100300      6/30/2016       12/31/2016  1
100300      6/30/2017       12/31/2017  1
```

Desired output:

```
event_id    period_start    period_end  rating
100300      2/8/2016        12/31/2016  1
100300      6/30/2017       12/31/2017  1
```

You can determine if a period is directly sequential by testing if the previous row's `period_end` equals the current row's `period_start` (this is true throughout the dataset to identify directly sequential periods).

I *think* there is a solution here involving `GROUP BY` but I'm not seeing it.  Any assistance would be great.  Thank you!

Comment: Gaps and islands problem.

Comment: @shawnt00 - solvable problem?  I'll also do a Google search on 'gaps and islands'

Comment: Easy enough with analytic functions. I know nothing about Presto though.

Comment: A non-Presto example would be helpful - maybe I can then re-create it in Presto

Comment: @NickBraunagel . . . Can there be overlap between the periods?  Or are adjacent periods always when the dates are equal?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - there will never be overlap of any periods, just the adjacent periods always when dates are equal, as you state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The key idea is to use `lag()` to find where the value changes and then do a cumulative sum to assign groups.

However, I have come to prefer a lag on the *date* column rather than the *value* column.  It turns out, this is much more convenient when you have multiple values that might change.

In your case, this looks like:

```
select event_id, min(period_start), max(period_end), rating
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_period_end = period_end then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by event_id order by period_start) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(period_end) over (partition by event_id, rating order by period_start) as prev_period_end
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by event_id, rating, grp;
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the help; everything is working on my end.  FYI - I changed the `CASE` to: `WHEN c.prev_psc_end_date = c.psc_start_date THEN 0`.

Comment: Same as my answer. But higher rep always wins, right? Does Presto not allow CTEs?

Comment: You didn't actually provide an answer, so I can't accept anything from you.  Do you want a +1 on your comment? lol

Comment: My answer has been sitting there for an hour. I don't really care about rep. It's just that an acknowledgement for time spent seems fair.

Comment: Well I believe the sum is incorrect. Set up a sequence of adjacent dates where the rating changes each time. See if that result is what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
with a as (
    select *,
        case when lag(period_end) over (partition by event_id, rating order by period_start) = period_start
           then 0 else 1 end as brk
    from T
) b as (
    select *,
        sum(brk) over (partition by event_id, rating order by period_start) as grp
    from a
)
select event_id, min(period_start) as period_start, max(period_end) as period_end, rating
from b
group by event_id, grp, rating
order by event_id, grp, rating
```

Determine which rows are breaks in a series, marking them as 1. Number the groups by counting breaks, a running total. Use `group by` to collapse into single row.

Comment: Compare the two results here: https://rextester.com/WUFF44371